# How can I list those ID's what's not in the where clause?

Tags: t-sql, where-clause

I've got 2 tables Books and Copy's.
I counted those copy's where the time between 2 dates and grouped by bookID, what's between 2 dates and I've got the following result:

- BookID Copy Quantity
- 111111  1
- 222222  888
- 333333 666

  ```
  SELECT BookID, Count(CopyID)
   from Copy 
   INNER join Book on Book.BookID = Copy.BookdID
   where Copy.Time BETWEEN '2017.12.11' AND '2017.12.15'
  GROUP BY BOOKID
  ```

Here is my problem: I want to count all that copy what's got the same BookID in my query.
For example: I've got 1 result for `BookID 111111`,but if there is 8 copy I want to somehow include to my result.

Comment: So you want `copyquantity-Count(copyid)`?

Comment: Exactly, I want to Count all the copy :)

Comment: You don't show us both of your tables, so how can we help and write the right SQL query? Did you try writing what I suggested, replacing `copyquantity` with the real column name and probably prefixing it with `Books.`?

Comment: If the output list contains only the BookID and counts of copies, there is no need for the Books table. Of course if any other field that is now shown in the question is required, we need to join to Books master table

Comment: Well I haven't got copyquantity column, but that's right, I didnt really need the booktable :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben, following query displays count of all copies for books where there is at least one copy between given two dates

Please check if it outputs what is required

```
select
    b.BookID, Count(c.CopyID)
from Book as b
left outer join Copy as c
    on b.BookID = c.BookID
where b.BookID in (
    select
        distinct c.BookID
    from Copy as c
    where c.Time BETWEEN '2017.12.11' AND '2017.12.15'
)
group by
    b.BookID
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need to book table

```
select c.ID, count(*)
from copy c 
where exists ( select 1 
                 from copy 
                where copy.ID = c.ID 
                  and copy.Time BETWEEN '2017.12.11' AND '2017.12.15' 
             )
group by c.ID
```